# IBM ACE (NEW) - Invoking Rest API defined in WADL or API with no swagger definition

Tags: ibm-app-connect

Rest request node only accepts rest API defined in swagger in order to be used no options to import WADL. What is the alternatives or correct approach implementing this kind of integration?

When I tries http request, ive got nothing:

```
{}
Compute Node:
 SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestLine.Method = 'GET';
         SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.HTTP.RequestURL = 'http://service.miataru.com/v1/GetLocationGeoJSON/' || InputLocalEnvironment.REST.Input.Parameters.deviceID;
```

flow:
in -> compute node -> http req node - out

Comment: rpj123 - You can convert the WADL into SWAGGER file using some online tool. Regarding the code you have shown, is it working in POSTMAN ? what error do you get when you run this in IBM ACE ? Have you tried running this in debug mode in the toolkit.

Comment: Hi Rohan, your comment helps a lot. I tried converting wadl into swagger using swagger editor. There is another way mentioned by my colleague (using soap node in iib), though i haven't tried it. Thanks by the way!

Comment: rpj123 - I have put a response in the answer section. please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your WADL to SWAGGER(OpenAPI) specification using any online converters. For example, you could use https://www.apimatic.io/transformer/#supported-formats